# Cannot create mysql table using Flask Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create two tables: bulkdata and bulkinfo. each bulk info has many bulkdata. this is my flask models:

```
from datetime import datetime

from ..extensions import db


class Bulkinfo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bulkinfo'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    hashed_id = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    
    project_hashed_id = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('project.hashed_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

    bulkdata = db.relationship('Bulkdata', backref='user', cascade='all, delete')

    def __repr__(self)->str:
        return f'BULKINFO - User: {self.project.user.username} Project: {self.project}'
    

from datetime import datetime

from ..extensions import db

class Bulkdata(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bulkdata'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    source_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    source_title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    source_url = db.Column(db.String(255))
    target_title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    target_url = db.Column(db.String(255))
    replaced_heading = db.Column(db.String(255))
    generated_section = db.Column(db.Text)
    anchor = db.Column(db.String(80))
    success = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    err_msg = db.Column(db.String(255))
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)

    bulkinfo_hashed_id = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('bulkinfo.hashed_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

    def __repr__(self)->str:
        return f'{self.target_title}'
```

running flask db upgrade gives me this error:

```
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1005, 'Can\'t create table `linkage`.`bulkdata` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')
[SQL: ALTER TABLE bulkdata ADD FOREIGN KEY(bulkinfo_hashed_id) REFERENCES bulkinfo (hashed_id) ON DELETE CASCADE]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

can anyone help me what am I doing wrong? I can't find it for the life of me.

Comment: If anyone interested, I deleted both table, replaced bulkinfo with bulkindex table:

ran the commands again and it worked.